# Scrot install failure

Tags: macos

I have Mac OS X Yosemite, and I have recently tried to install Scrot. I found online that I was supposed to use:

```
sudo apt-get install scrot
```

but that doesn't work. It says that the command is 'not found'. I have looked it up, and Homebrew does not work. It gives me an error. I have tried everything that can be found online, and yet it still doesn't work when I write

```
brew install scrot
```

Please help!

Comment: have you tried **brew install scrot**? That worked for me.

Comment: I did that, and at the end it said, "error: No formulae found in taps."

Comment: you should add that to your original question as "homebrew" is not actually a command.

Comment: Done. Now says "Brew install scrot."